# Error 301 on AJAX POST request after enabling ssl on Apache Server

Tags: ajax, laravel, ssl, cors

I am building a simple Laravel based REST API (it's served through apache based Ubuntu server) that is consumed by an Angular 6 web application via its HttpClient module.

It was working correctly on my localhost until I uploaded it to Firebase hosting (which enables https). So I had to implement a commercial SSL certificate on my server, it worked just fine attending POST request through POSTMAN or GET requests through Google Chrome, but when I try to call it from my web app it shows this error:

[image]

My client code is really straight forward:

```
generateReport(data) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({"Content-Type":"application/json"});
    return this.httpClient.post(this.env.apiURL+'excel/show/',
      data,
      {headers:headers});
  }
```

And this is my virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName eduardoibarra.com
        ServerAlias www.eduardoibarra.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine  on
        SSLCertificateFile /root/www_eduardoibarra_com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/server.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /root/COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
        <Directory /var/www/html>
                Order Allow,Deny
                Options FollowSymLinks
                Allow from all
                AllowOverride All
                RewriteEngine On
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So summing up,

> Http server + localhost client environment = **worked correctly**
>
> Https server + POSTMAN OR Chrome = **works correctly**
>
> Https server + https client environment = **gives above 301 error**

*Note: I also enabled CORS on Laravel through barry's cors library, directly on the public/index.php file using headers and on the virtualhost configuration with the same results.

Comment: Did you `allowedOrigins => ['troy-da34b.firebaseapp.com']`, by the way your server root needs to be `/var/www/html/public` so you just can request `POST https://eduardoibarra.com/excel/show`

Comment: Thanks Thijs Bouwes, I did both of those things with no luck (calling https://eduardoibarra.com/excel/show results in a 404 because the way laravel works). Adding the domain to the allowedOrigins resulted in the same 301 error.

Comment: Hmm,  eduardoibarra.com/excel/show shouldn't result in a 404 if you setup apache to serve the public directory. Did you reload apache?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that my apache server is serving the /var/www/html/ I have several projects in this directory, one of them is the laravel folder. I'll try to correct this with a subdomain but it was working correctly before I moved to https as is.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this structure, its a security risk. Move the project to there own folders and serve them from there.
Laravel is intended to be served from the public directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need to allow the `OPTIONS` method explicitly in the `Access-Allow-Control-Methods`. Also in apache you should catch the `OPTIONS` and return http status `200` since `OPTIONS` returns `301` redirection.

Try something like the apache settings below:

```
<Location /laravel/public>
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
    Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
</Location>
```